# Facebook realtime API: do removed friends trigger an update call?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Naturally the documentation doesn't make this distinction, which makes me think it doesn't.  So very succinctly - does anyone know whether a user losing a friend triggers a realtime update callback?  If so, is it the same if the user removed said friend or if the user was 'unfriended'?

If I've missed something in the documentation about this then I apologise, but I assure you I have looked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Facebook Realtime API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) does seem to be providing notifications about certain user fields and connections for the [User](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) object. Connections to which you can subscribe include for `User object` include: feed, `friends`, likes, checkins, location, events.

And when you have successfully subscribe for `user object subscription`, everytime users `friends` is updated, your `callback` server will be notified.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I was specifically wondering if the removal of friends triggers the callback.  Of course I can just test it when I have time, but I thought somebody might know through experience (and therefore know it's almost certainly undocumented quirks).

Comment: Yeah, whenever the friends list is updated for a user (which does include the friending and unfriending) the callback gets triggered